# How to change theme and style on termux?

Tags: termux

Please how do I change the theme and style on my termux app ?

After installing all the necessary packages, I have tried `termux-style`, f, c.

I have tried several ways of editing the termux app on my Android but still no success I have tried the termux-style command, c, f, and besides I tried them after installing packages and I don't know what else to do

Answer (score 4):

1. Install [Termux:Styling](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.termux.styling) app from Google Play (If you want to support them) or [Termux:Styling](https://f-droid.org/en/packages/com.termux.styling/) from Fdroid (Free).
2. Open Termux app.
3. Long-press your screen. A dialog will show up.
4. Click **MORE...**. Another dialog wil show up.
5. Click **Style**. Surprise...surprise... Another dialog will show up.
6. Click **CHOOSE COLOR** for theme or **CHOOSE FONT** for font. Jeez... Another dialog will show up.
7. Now you'll see a list of colors/fonts that you can choose from. Select any.
8. Press back twice to confirm your choice. Tada.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Will do so immediately...

Comment: Anyone know a way to get these to match the system theme? When it turns dark out, the termux theme stays in light mode.